# Why can't I convert DNA to mRNA in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dna-sequence

Code:

```py
n = 3

DNA-Sequence = { #dictionary of DNA
    "Phenylalanine": ["UUU", "UUC"],
    "Leucine": ["UUA", "CUU", "CUC", "CUA", "CUG", "UUG"],
    "Isoleucine": ["AUU", "AUC", "AUA"],
    "Methionine": "AUG",
    "Valine": ["GUU", "GUC", "GUA", "GUG"],
    "Serine": ["UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG"],
    "Proline": ["CCU", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG"],
    "Threonine": ["ACU", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG"],
    "Alanine": ["GCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG"],
    "Tyrosine": ["UAU", "UAC"],
    "Histidine": ["CAU", "CAC"],
    "Glutamine": ["CAA", "CAG"],
    "Asparagine": ["AAU", "AAC"],
    "Lysine": ["AAA", "AAG"],
    "Asparatic Acid": ["GAU", "GAC"],
    "Glutamic Acid": ["GAA", "GAG"],
    "Cysteine": ["UGU", "UGC"],
    "Trytophan": "UGG",
    "Arginine": ["CGU", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "AGG", "AGA"],
    "Serine": ["AGU", "AGC"],
    "Glycine": ["GGU", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG"]
}

lookup_dict = {k: key for key, values in DNA-Sequence.items() for k in values} #this is used to find the values in the dictionary using the inputDNA
inputDNA = input("Enter your DNA sequence: ")
inputDNA = inputDNA.upper()
print("Your DNA sequence is", inputDNA)
str(inputDNA)
RNA = inputDNA.replace('C', 'G') #this is me trying to convert DNA sequence to RNA
RNA = RNA.replace('A', "U") #this is me trying to convert DNA sequence to RNA
RNA = RNA.replace('T', 'A') #this is me trying to convert DNA sequence to RNA
print(RNA)

b = len(inputDNA)

if b % 3 == 0: #if the length of inputDNA is a multiple of 3
  for k in (inputDNA[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(inputDNA), n)):
    for _, values in DNA-Sequence.items():
      if k in values:
        print(lookup_dict[k], end=" ")
        break
    else: #if the length of inputDNA is not a multiple of 3
      print("I hate u")
```

What happened:

```
Enter your DNA sequence: CCATAGCACGTT
Your DNA sequence is: CCATAGCACGTT
GGUAUGGUGGAA
Proline I hate u
Histidine I hate u
```

What I want to happen:

```
Enter your DNA sequence: CCATAGCACGTT
Your DNA sequence is: CCATAGCACGTT #this is because I need to convert DNA sequence to RNA but I am not sure of the formula and how to do it in python
GGUAUCGUGCAA
Your amino acids chain is: Glycine, Isoleucine, Valine, Glutamine
```

Why do I get the output of `A`, and how do I fix it to become the output I want? I know that I am not doing `RNA = RNA.replace('G', 'C')` but when I do that, the output becomes

```
Enter your DNA sequence: CAACAUGCU
Your DNA sequence is CAACAUGCU
A
Glutamine Histidine Alanine
```

Or something along those lines, but definitely **not** what I what do happen. Please help?

Comment: Can you simplify that code and do something to make it easier to read? Better variable names would be good, for one, maybe even some comments.

Comment: do you want to convert `GUCAT` sequence TO `CAGTA` for example ? am i right ? Is that the problem ?

Comment: That innermost for loop, for example, is painful. What’s wrong with just `if k in xdict.values()`? What’s the last `elif` for? If `b % 3 == 0` is false, then `b % 3 != 0` must be true, no?

Comment: Let me try and edit to make this a bit more clear.

Comment: I think @MohVahedi is asking a good question: What is this program doing?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I am trying to firstly change a given DNA sequence to mRNA and then print out what kind of a DNA it is.

Comment: @MohVahedi I am trying to firstly change a given DNA sequence to mRNA and then print out what kind of a DNA it is.

Comment: @GuyOverThere I’m not a biologist, that doesn’t make things clearer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following regarding the replacement where you encounter you problems, as far as I've seen; It can be done with 1 translate call or 2 depend on you preferences:

```
a = input("Enter your DNA sequence: ")
a = a.upper()
print("Your DNA sequence is", a)
# RNA = a.translate(str.maketrans({'G': 'C', 'C': 'G'}))
# RNA = RNA.translate(str.maketrans({'A': 'U', 'T': 'A'}))
RNA = a.translate(str.maketrans({'G': 'C', 'C': 'G', 'A': 'U', 'T': 'A'}))
print(RNA)
```

The output is:

```
Enter your DNA sequence: CCATAGCACGTT
Your DNA sequence is CCATAGCACGTT
GGUAUCGUGCAA
```

Regarding to the printing of the amino acids:

```
b = len(RNA)

if b % 3 == 0: #if the length of inputDNA is a multiple of 3
  for k in (RNA[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(RNA), n)):
    for kk, val in DNA_Sequence.items():
      if k in val:
        print(kk, end=" ")
        break
else: #if the length of inputDNA is not a multiple of 3
    print("I hate u")
```

*Notice*

The table is not a DNA table but RNA (you have `U`) there thus you need to use the `RNA` in the loops and the output is:

> Glycine Isoleucine Valine Glutamine

Comment: Can’t that be done in a single translate operation?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile It can, I wanted it to be more clear for the user ti read

Comment: I guess you can always create the dict outside of the function, those are generally very easy to read because they can naturally be spread over multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a pandas solution for this for another person:

```
import pandas as pd
df =  pd.DataFrame(list(xdict.items()))

import re
def lookupKeys(df, key):
  name = []
  matches = re.findall(r'...', key)
  for match in matches:
      name.append(df[df[1].apply(lambda x: True if key in x else x) == True][0].reset_index()[0][0])
  return name


lookupKeys(df, 'GGUAUCGUGCAA')                                                                                                                                                      
# ['Glycine', 'Isoleucine', 'Valine', 'Glutamine']
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok there were some syntax errors, but made it to up and running...

```
n = 3

xdict = {
    "Phenylalanine": ["UUU", "UUC"],
    "Leucine": ["UUA", "CUU", "CUC", "CUA", "CUG", "UUG"],
    "Isoleucine": ["AUU", "AUC", "AUA"],
    # Put the 'AUG' on brackets []
    "Methionine": ["AUG"],
    "Valine": ["GUU", "GUC", "GUA", "GUG"],
    "Serine": ["UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG"],
    "Proline": ["CCU", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG"],
    "Threonine": ["ACU", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG"],
    "Alanine": ["GCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG"],
    "Tyrosine": ["UAU", "UAC"],
    "Histidine": ["CAU", "CAC"],
    "Glutamine": ["CAA", "CAG"],
    "Asparagine": ["AAU", "AAC"],
    "Lysine": ["AAA", "AAG"],
    "Asparatic Acid": ["GAU", "GAC"],
    "Glutamic Acid": ["GAA", "GAG"],
    "Cysteine": ["UGU", "UGC"],
    "Trytophan": "UGG",
    "Arginine": ["CGU", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "AGG", "AGA"],
    "Serine": ["AGU", "AGC"],
    "Glycine": ["GGU", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG"]
}

lookup_dict = {k: key for key, values in xdict.items() for k in values}
a = input("Enter your DNA sequence: ")
a = a.upper()
print("Your DNA sequence is", a)
str(a)
RNA = a.replace('C', 'G')
RNA = RNA.replace('A', "U")
RNA = RNA.replace('T', 'A')
print(RNA)

b = len(a)

# Introduced a new flag variable
val = ''

if b % 3 == 0:
    # a replaced with RNA
  for k in (RNA[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(a), n)):
      val += lookup_dict[k] + ' '

elif b % 3 != 0:
  print("Try again.")


print('Name', val)
```

You were looping via 'a' but it should be `RNA`.
Read the comments to know the other changes...